# Can't check equality with unknowns in Prolog

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

When trying with a simple program to find numbers that multiply to make 100, I can check for set values, like `prod_hundred(2, 50)`, but if I want to find a value with `prod_hundred(4, X)`, I get :

```
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
   [1] 4*_1680=:=100
```

I know this is because I can't use '=:=' to evaluate with unknowns, but with == it just compares `"2*50"` to `"100"`, instead of evaluating `2*50`

**Code:**

```
prod_hundred(X, Y) :- X*Y =:= 100.

?- prod_hundred(4, X).

Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
   [1] 2*_1680=:=100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Solve for X" is harder than evaluating `2*50` to get the result; it needs math knowledge of how to rearrange the equation to `100/4 = X`. Classic Prolog doesn't have that built in, you would have to code it yourself.

But that kind of thing is in newer constraint solver libraries such as `clpfd` in SWI Prolog which gives you `#=` and can solve by finding integer answers to number problems:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

prod_hundred(X, Y) :- 
    X*Y #= 100.
```

Then:

```
?- prod_hundred(4, X).
X = 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
factor(F,N) :- integer(N),
  L is N // 2 ,
  ( between(1,L,F) ; N ),
  0 =:= N rem F
  .
  
factors(X,Y,Z) :- integer(Z),
  factor(X,Z),
  factor(Y,Z),
  Z is X * Y
  .

prod_hundred(X,Y) :- factors(X,Y,100).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
makes_mult(Tot, X, Y) :-
    between(1, Tot, X),
    divmod(Tot, X, Y, 0).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(findall((X, Y), makes_mult(100, X, Y), Tuples)).
% 220 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (100% CPU, 575084 Lips)
Tuples = [(1,100),(2,50),(4,25),(5,20),(10,10),(20,5),(25,4),(50,2),(100,1)].
```

Comment: Using divmod/4 is a nice trick. But why are you computing TotHalf is Tot div 2?

A more simple-minded (and less efficient) solution is:
makes_mult(Tot,X,Y) :- between(1,Tot,X), between(1,Tot,Y), Tot is X*Y.